# fixing datatable:rowsPerPageTemplate style

Tags: css, primefaces

My goal is to fix the width of rowsPerPageTemplate im p:datatable
(i'm using primefaces and HTML5)

**what i did:**

in my css i fixed the style of the select menus as follow

```
select{width : 100% !important;}
```

the problem is that rowsPerPageTemplate took the same width of selectmenu which is not expected ,i want that rowsPerPageTemplate take customized width different than the width of the select menu, so i added this code in the css

```
select.customWidth
{
 width:45px;
}
```

i called this style in my xhtml page as below

```
<p:dataTable
rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
styleClass="customWidth">
```

Howver it seems that customWidth is not taken in account

[screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HJMq.png)

can anyone guide me to the right point

Comment: This is all just a plain html and css related 'issue'. And with 100% it is not fixed, so please be more specific in what you want. E.g. with screenshots and more.

Comment: My goal is to fix the width of rowsPerPageTemplate to 10 em because it take the same style of select menues ( width : 100% ! important)

Comment: My problem that rowsPerPageTemplate take the same style of select menues

Comment: Then change your css selectors to be more specific. Or create an additional css rule with a selector that 'restores' the css of the rowsPerPageTemplate. Again, all basic css/html. Nothing primefaces speflcific

Comment: In my CSS i have added a new rule select.customWidth but it seems that it is not possible to override the first rule (pls see my edit)

Comment: Look at the generated html. Is the customWidth directly applied on the select? Most likely not, so your selector is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I added this code in the style sheet to set the width of rowsPerPageTemplate (10em in my case )

```
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-rpp-options {
margin-left: 1em;
margin-right: 1em;
background-image: none;
width: 10em !important;
```

}